# Relation between norms of two matrices

Tags: matrices

Is there a relation between the norm $\|A\|$ of a nonsingular symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ and the norm of its inverse matrix $A^{-1}$?

Comment: As Dominik points out in his answer, one quantity is controlled by the largest eigenvalue, and the other is controlled by the smallest eigenvalue.  The only relation between the two is that the smallest eigenvalue must be smaller than the largest :). The condition number of $A$ is a measure of how wide the gap is between those two eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

The only inequality I'm aware of is $1 = \|A A^{-1}\| \le \|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\|$ [if $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm].

Other than that, you can't really say much about the relation between the two norms. The Norm of $A$ is the biggest absolute eigenvalue of $A$, while the norm of $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of the smallest absolute eigenvalue of $A$. It is easy to see that all combinations that satisfy $1 \le \|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\|$ can occur.

Comment: you have to introduce the using norm.

Comment: I did mention that I assume the norm to be the standard operator norm.

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistake.I wanted to comment for question, not here.

Comment: I changed $||A||$ to $\|A\|$, which is standard.  The difference becomes conspicuous (if it wasn't already) when you contrast $||A||||B||$ with $\|A\|\|B\|$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Dominik Your inequality is reversed, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, it definitely improves readability.

Comment: @ErickWong You are right, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: I agree, you can't say much about the relation, in addition maybe $\| A^{-1} \| = \left( \min_{\| x \| = 1} \| A x \| \right)^{-1}$. I do have one question, what makes you say that "The Norm of A is the biggest absolute eigenvalue of A..."? Doesn't this depend on the chosen vector norm?

Comment: @user190080 Yes, the calculation via eigenvalues only works if you choose the euclidean norm in both spaces.

Comment: yeah...that's what I thought, thanks. In your answer it just sounds like a very general statement, that's why I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about the operator norm i.e $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$ we know that for a symmetric positive definite matrix we have $\|A\|=\max\lambda_i$ where the set $\{\lambda_i\}$ is the spectrum of $A$. So we immediately get

$$\|A^{-1}\|={1\over\min\lambda_i}$$

Because the spectrum of $A^{-1}$ is the set $\{{1\over\lambda_i}\}$

Comment: but the spectral norm (with $||A||_p,p=2$) is just one interpretation of the induced norm of an operator...

Comment: @user190080 The OP only specifies "the norm", and this is the most reasonable interpretation in the absence of any qualifiers.

Comment: @ErickWong I don't mind using the spectral norm at all but reading all the answers one could get the impression that *the norm* (operator norm) of a spd matrix always equals the spectral norm. In my opinion this needs some clarification which is exactly what I wanted to provide with my comments. Besides this I am totally fine with the given answers...